Error while upgrading Unreal Engine project to source
enter image description here"Hello, I'm using Unreal Engine 5.3.2 and trying to upgrade my project to Unreal Engine source code, but I'm encountering the error shown in the screenshot. When I create an empty project, meaning without any plugins, I can upgrade the project to Unreal Engine source code without any issues. However, when I include the PlayFab plugin in my project, I get this error. I've searched for this error on Google but haven't found any results. Is there anyone who can help?"

I disabled live coding but nothing changed. 2) Instead of copying the plugin to the plugins folder, I added it from the Unreal Engine plugins section by clicking 'Add,' and the result is the same error

